# Change value in for-loop whilst looping

Tags: python

I'm stuck on a dice exercise. For each dice that rolls 6, they need to be *excluded from the count and rolled again*. Problem is that I don't know how to change the value of a `for` `range` loop whilst looping through it, and I'm not sure how to attack it otherwise. Here's where I'm at:

```
numRolls = 10
initSum = 0

for i in range(0,numRolls):
    diceScore = random.randint(1,6) 
    if(diceScore == 6):
        print("You rolled a 6! You receive two extra rolls.")
        numRolls = numRolls + 2
        # Not making its way to the top of the for-loop
    else:
        totalSum = initSum + diceScore
print("Done! You've rolled a total of ",totalSum)
totalSum = 0
```

I'm guessing `numRolls` in the `for`-loop is out of scope. The alternative solutions I've come up with would mean absolutely endless amount of separate rolls. Randoming between 1 and 5 is not a viable option.. :)

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this smaller example:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    i = i + 1
```

This is equivalent to

```
i = 0
i = i + 1
i = 1
i = i + 1
i = 2
i = i + 1
```

I'm sure you see why your idea doesn't work.

Use `while` instead of `for`.
If you count down instead of up, you don't need any more variables.

```
while numRolls > 0:
    numRolls = numRolls - 1
    diceScore = random.randint(1,6) 
    if(diceScore == 6):
        print("You rolled a 6! You receive two extra rolls.")
        numRolls = numRolls + 2
    else:
        totalSum = initSum + diceScore
print("Done! You've rolled a total of ",totalSum)
totalSum = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you care to explain why `while` accepts the + 2 but `for` doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

Use a while loop and initialize the counter outside the loop. Then increment both, the counter and numRolls, as and when you want inside the loop

```
numRolls = 10
rollsSoFar = 0
initSum = 0

while rollsSoFar <= nulRolls:
    diceScore = random.randint(1,6) 
    if(diceScore == 6):
        print("You rolled a 6! You receive two extra rolls.")
        numRolls = numRolls + 2
    else:
        totalSum = initSum + diceScore
    rollsSoFar += 1
print("Done! You've rolled a total of ",totalSum)
totalSum = 0
```

**Edit: added explanation for why this works**

When you create a for loop like `for i in range(0,numRolls)` you are calling the function `range()` and passing it parameters `0` and `numRolls`. `range()` then gives you back a generator (let's call this generator `rollsGenerator`) that you iterate over. This generator has been created to give you values `0` to `numRolls-1` inclusive.

So your for-loop effectively evaluates to something like `for i in rollsGenerator` before the first iteration begins.

Then, inside the loop, when you increment the value of `numRolls`, it doesn't change the number of iterations because `rollsGenerator` has already been created with the original value of `numRolls`. The for-loop does not call `range(0,numRolls)` on every iteration, and so the generator stays the same no matter how you change `numRolls`.

By using a while-loop, you are basically changing your code to check the latest value of `numRolls` on each iteration and you skip the whole generator business.

Comment: Gotta be < numRolls if the count starts at 0, right? Else I'll get one too many? Would try right away but rendering something

Comment: Also, care to explain why `while` will accept the + 2 but `for` won't?

Comment: I think it should be `<=` but I haven't tried it either - should be an easy tweak either way. I'll also add an explanation to the answer for why this works and your code doesn't.